# T-SQL Select Equality Result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following snippet, I am getting an error in line #4 (Incorrect Syntax near '=').  I need to have an equality result displayed as a column in a select statement.

```
declare @five int
set @five = 5

declare @bool bit
set @bool = (@five = 6)

select @five, @bool
```

The result set should have two columns:
5   false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

T-SQL does not have a real boolean type. It is a weird situation. Here is the solution:

```
set @bool = case when @five = 6 then 1 else 0 end
```

Truth expressions, which would be of boolean type in other languages, don't have a type in T-SQL. You can only use truth expressions in special syntactic places like `where`, `if` and `case`.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. They all work. @usr gave the quickest response though.

Comment: @usr as far as I know only MySQL has a "real" boolean.

Comment: SQL Server supports the [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603) data type.  (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.)  There is a [boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one.

Comment: SQL Server does have the `bit` but boolean expressions are not of type bit! They don't have a type and they can't be assigned to anything.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `CASE` statement around that logic:

```
declare @five int
set @five = 5

declare @bool bit
set @bool = CASE WHEN @five = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

select @five, @bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `CASE`

```
declare @five int
set @five = 5

select @five, CASE WHEN @five = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

As an exotic approach - if you don't want to use CASE logic - bitwise operands work too:

```
declare @five int
set @five = 5

declare @bool bit
set @bool = (@five ^ 5)

select @five, ~@bool
```